# Elements in flexbox div snap their position if another element is removed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have a flex div with `flex-direction` set to either `column` or `column-reverse` and `align-items` set to `flex-start` or `flex-end`. This makes the children inside it stack to a top/bottom - left/right position.

Now when I remove a child that is under a stack, for e.g.
in the below stack everything is aligned top left

```
Element A
Element B <- this element
Element C
...
...
...
```

So if `Element B` is removed, then `Element C` will snap-up and join `Element A`, I want this to be animated so that the div moves smoothly.

I tried using `transition` with `top` and `left` but it does not work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is some code for more understanding:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="elA">Element A</div>
    <div id="elB">Element B</div>
    <div id="elC">Element C</div>
</div>
```

The Css:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
}

#elA, #elB, #elC {
  transition: top 1s, left 1s;
}

.hide {
/* something can be added here */
}
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function removeEl(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    el.className += 'hide'; // can be used for animation
    window.setTimeout(() => el.remove(), 1000); // to actually remove
}

removeEl('elB');
```

Comment: You could add an [eventListener `animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) to the element. Then animate it's height/width to 0 and after that remove it.

Comment: transition works in terms of "as soon as a given css rule gets applied" to an element. But since you are deleting an element, there's no way to make it work like that. Unless the removal was made applying a css rule with display:none. Maybe if you include a working code in a snippet, someone will just add what's needed to make the sliding animated as soon as an item gets off the stack

Comment: There's also a [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) if you want a transition instead of animation.

Comment: @Michel I want to avoid javascript

Comment: @DiegoDeVita added code

Comment: @M.ImranMamda so what is the `function removeEL(id)`? Not javascript?

Comment: @Michel wanted to avoid animations in javascript, all other animations are done in css, the code I have shown is minimal code

Comment: even if I could remove this js function and use css instead to remove the elements, that would be fine, but then I guess we will have lots of dom elements with display:none sitting in the dom

Comment: @M.ImranMamda You can do both. With JS add the eventlistener and  change the class to trigger the animation. Let CSS handle the animation. When CSS is ready, it triggers the JS function defined in `animationend`. Then you can remove it.